# Postgres Operator not starting as NodePort

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I am trying to setup Crunchydata/Postgres Operator on CentOS 7 by following this [link](https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgres-operator/4.6.2/quickstart/#postgresql-operator-installer).  Configuration settings are as follows

```
CentOS:  CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
```

Kubectl:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.5", GitCommit:"6b1d87acf3c8253c123756b9e61dac642678305f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-03-18T01:10:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.5", GitCommit:"6b1d87acf3c8253c123756b9e61dac642678305f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-03-18T01:02:01Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I downloaded postgres-operator.yml as shown below

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator/v4.6.2/installers/kubectl/postgres-operator.yml > postgres-operator.yml
```

I took a copy of 'postgres-operator.yml'and changed the 'ServiceType' from 'ClusterIP' to 'Nodeport'.  Difference is shown below

```
[root@devk8s ~]# diff pgo.yaml postgres-operator.yml
192c192
<     service_type: "NodePort"
---
>     service_type: "ClusterIP"
```

I expect the 'service' to run as 'NodePort'.  However, despite changing the ServiceType to 'NodePort' it runs as 'ClusterIP'

```
[root@re-devk8s-control02 ~]# kubectl get svc postgres-operator -n pgo
NAME                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
postgres-operator   ClusterIP   10.99.29.185   <none>        8443/TCP,4171/TCP,4150/TCP   9m55s
```

I deleted the namespace and tried it afresh but it does not work

Kindly let me know what's wrong with my setting or am I doing something wrong ?

**EDIT:**

I was able to create cluster 'hippo' as type 'NodePort' using Postgres Operator as shown below

```
[root@control02 ~]# kubectl get svc -n pgo
NAME                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                         AGE
hippo                        NodePort    10.99.186.224    <none>        2022:32476/TCP,5432:31541/TCP   133m
hippo-backrest-shared-repo   ClusterIP   10.100.128.186   <none>        2022/TCP                        133m
postgres-operator            ClusterIP   10.105.189.152   <none>        8443/TCP,4171/TCP,4150/TCP      165m
```

I was able to curl (empty reply) from worker1 and worker2 to PGO of K8S cluster as shown below

```
[root@devk8s ~]# curl 172.xx.x.1:31541
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
[root@devk8s ~]# curl 172.xx.x.2:31541
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Port is on listening state on worker nodes

```
[root@worker02 ~]# netstat -ant | grep 31
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:31541           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:32476           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

However, when I try to hit '172.xx.x.1:31541' or '172.xx.x.2:31541' browser says 'Connection was reset'.

I am not sure how to fix this issue and also not sure about 'empty reply from server'

Answer (score 0):

You were changing the ConfigMap holding the options used for the Postgres clusters it creates, not for the operator itself. The service is for the operator, not for Postgres. Continue on with the install and make an actual Postgres cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Kindly see my edit and help me

Comment: Postgres does not use HTTP, curl or a browser will not work. You can use `psql`, the Postgres CLI tool. Or any other Postgres client.